# SPOJ:Card Shuffling

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

Recently I started solving questions on online judges. I am stuck in [this question in SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CODESPTC/):

> Here is an algorithm for shuffling N cards:
>
> 1. The cards are divided into K equal piles, where K is a factor of N.
> 2. The bottom N / K cards belong to pile 1 in the same order (so the bottom card of the .initial pile is the bottom card of pile 1).
> 3. The next N / K cards from the bottom belong to pile 2, and so on.
> 4. Now the top card of the shuffled pile is the top card of pile 1. The next card is the top card of pile 2,..., the Kth card of the shuffled pile is the top card of pile K. Then (K + 1)th card is the card which is now at the top of pile 1, the (K + 2)nd is the card which is now at the top of pile 2 and so on.
>
> For example, if N = 6 and K = 3, the order of a deck of cards "ABCDEF" (top to bottom) when shuffled once would change to "ECAFDB".
>
> Given N and K, what is the least number of shuffles needed after which the pile is restored to its original order?

---

I tried simulating but it exceeds time limit. Is there any mathematical equation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a mathematical solution for this problem.

First let me start with some tips on how to approach such problems and then I will give some tips on the actual solution. I will not quite finish it so that there is still some challenge left.

So: how to approach such problems? What you did is actually a good start. Write a simulation and run it against some small cases. The simulation should be fairly fast there. Now you have some more values. Write them down on a piece of paper and start staring at them. You have fro instance if K = x<sub>1</sub> and N = y<sub>1</sub> then the result is z<sub>1</sub> and a lot more such pairs. Try to figure some formula. Focus on triples that have a fixed value for x, for y or for z. What do they have in common? And so on. You stare and usually you get a bright idea after some time :)

Now: some tips on this particular problem. Do a single iteration of the shuffling and note where each card goes. For instance card 1 goes in position 3 card 3 goes in position 2 and so on. Note that some chains will be formed this way - for instance in the example n=6, k=3, we have a chain of length 6: 1->3->2->6->4->5->1. Now compute the lengths of all the chains(each card will belong to exactly one chain) and try to find how does the answer depend on these lengths.

Hope this is enough to help you solve the problem.

EDIT: taking a look at the constraints simulating even a single iteration might be very slow. If that is the case, after you have done what I advice in my second tip try calculating the lengths of chains without actually having to simulate one shuffle

Comment: I am not sure I get your idea. The answer is direct formula from the length of the chains as described in my post.

Comment: m sorry for not being more articulate... we will start with value x=0... then using the above formula recursively get new position of the xth card.... once the card returns to 0 position, we have the original configuration... we count the number of iterations required in the whole process ... OR we can maintain a table of the next step...  is there any better approach? any group theory stuff?

Comment: Well my idea(at least for the first iteration) is somethink like what you describe - you need a bitmask to show which x-s you have already visited and then you use the formula `x = (x%k)*k + k - 1 - x/k` (I believe this is the correct one and it is a bit different from what you propose). For the final solution, though one will have to find direct formula for the length of the chain from a given card number.

Comment: could you please shed some more light on how to find the direct formula?

Comment: @vastutsav first of all: I am sorry it seems the mistake was actually mine - your formula for the next x is actually correct. I have interpreted the statement in a wrong way. As for the direct formula, I can not state it right away. I would write some simple code to calculate the chain length for some cases of N and k(for example for all N less then 20, k would be all their divisors and I would calculate all the chain lengths) and then try to figure out the formula.

Comment: I am using this formula: index = (K - ( index / S) - 1) + (index % S) * K; where S = N/K
This is also simpler to create: Assume an index as aS+b, so after piling it will go to (K-a)th pile, at (b)th hight. Now while merging these piles, the new index for the card wud be as per this equation.

Comment: @PushpRaj yes i also use this formula. The difficulty is: how to check whether the pile never goes to origin order? (This post miss it, the orginal problem have this requirements)