# Card Shuffling (SPOJ / Interviewstreet)

Tags: java, algorithm, shuffle

This question has been asked before, however none of them were answered definitively and I tried compiling all the information I found here. Feel free to merge/move to another stackexchange site if necessary.

Here are questions I found related to this:

- [SPOJ:Card Shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663079/spojcard-shuffling?rq=1)
- [Card Shuffling [SPOJ]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119214/card-shuffling-spoj)

The problem was initially posted as an Interviewstreet Code Sprint, but right now it's listed as [a practice problem](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4e904ba8b17ed). It's also been [ported to SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CODESPTC/).

Here's the problem statement:

> Here is an algorithm for shuffling N cards:
>
> 1) The cards are divided into K equal piles.
>
> 2) The bottom N / K cards
>   belong to pile 1 in the same order (so the bottom card of the initial
>   pile is the bottom card of pile 1).
>
> 3) The next N / K cards from the
>   bottom belong to pile 2, and so on.
>
> 4) Now the top card of the shuffled pile is the top card of pile 1. 
>   The next card is the top card of pile 2, ..., the Kth card of the shuffled pile is the top > card of pile K. Then (K + 1)th card is the card which is now at the top of
>   pile 1, the (K + 2)nd is the card which is now at the top of pile 2
>   and so on.
>
> For example, if N = 6 and K = 3, the order of a deck of cards "ABCDEF"
>   (top to bottom) when shuffled once would change to "ECAFDB".
>
> Given N and K, what is the least number of shuffles needed after which
>   the pile is restored to its original order?
>
> Input: The first line contains the number of test cases T. The next T
>   lines contain two integers each N and K.
>
> Output: Output T lines, one for each test case containing the minimum
>   number of shuffles needed. If the deck never comes back to its
>   original order, output -1.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - K will be a factor of N.
> - T <= 10000
> - **2 <= K <= N <= 10^9**

---

## Spoiler Alert - don't read below if you want to solve it yourself.

The problem can be translated as:

> **Find the number of times a K-way (perfect) [in-shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_shuffle) needs to be performed
>   to restore a deck of N cards to its initial ordering.**

I took two approaches to solving this problem. The first approach that came to mind was:

- find a formula that, given a position in the initial order would generate the card's next position
- use the formula to determine the number of shuffles it takes each card from the first pile (n / k in size) to return to its initial position
- return the least common multiple of the number of shuffles determined before

The complexity of this solution is O(n / k + max_number_of_suhffles). [Here's the actual implementation](https://github.com/cimi/problems/blob/master/interviewstreet/java/src/main/java/com/interviewstreet/ShuffleLCM.java). The problem with this is that it exceeds the maximum time, so I started to look for a formula that would allow me to get the number in near constant time.

The most I could optimize here (e.g. used some maps for caching computed values in the same permutation cycle etc.) was to make it pass 3/10 tests on interviewstreet.

---

I found [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/1285133), which assumes that the number of shuffles needed to return to the initial state is the [multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of K relative to N + 1. From the wiki:

```
As a consequence of Lagrange's theorem, ordn(a) always divides φ(n).
```

φ(n) is the [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient_function), ordn is the [group order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29) - what we're looking for. I found [this paper](http://scimath.unl.edu/MIM/files/MATExamFiles/Hastings_FinalMEXP.pdf) that uses φ to compute the number of shuffles, but it's only for a 2-way in-shuffle, not k-way.

Here are the steps for this implementation:

- precomputed the list of primes < 100 000
- computed `φ(N+1)` from its prime factors.
- determined all of `φ(N + 1)`'s factors by combining its prime factors in all possible ways.
- tried each factor in turn and get the smallest one, `x`, which verifies `k ^ x % N + 1 = 1`

This implementation is also [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/cimi/problems/blob/master/interviewstreet/java/src/main/java/com/interviewstreet/ShuffleMultOrder.java).

This runs really fast, but the automatic grader gives me a "wrong answer" classification for 9 out of 10 tests, both on SPOJ and Interviewstreet.

I tried comparing the output from the two implementations, but for the testcases I put in (known result and random), the two implementations always output the same thing. This is strange, since I'm pretty sure that the first algorithm is correct I assume that the second one should be as well.

The "wrong answer" classification could come from a runtime error in the code, but nothing jumps out as a possible cause for this.

I did not take into account the case in which no number shuffles can return the deck to the initial state - my understanding is that this is not possible. A finite number of perfect shuffles will eventually restore the initial ordering, even though the number of shuffles may be really high.

If you took the time to read this, thanks. :) I'm curious about the problem, I'd like to have it solved.

Comment: Same Here.. I tried it with mathemetical formula and 7/10 cases shows Time limit exceeding. Though I am NOT sure about the test cases.

Comment: Note that in http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CODESPTC/ we have 2 <= K <= N <= 10^9. Are you sure you have enough primes?

Comment: After looking at the above, and fiddling with cases 3*2 and 3*3 I conjecture that if you mark the cards a 1, 2, 3...N then a shuffle leaves the pack as x, 2x, 3x, ..Nx mod (N+1), where you can work out what x is by looking to see what ends up in position 1. If so, you need the order of x in the group of numbers mod N+1 coprime to N+1 - which I think is your second approach with a slightly different multiplier. Could you check the idea and simplify your code by simply checking x, x^2, x^3... until you find one that comes out as 1?

Comment: thanks for the hint, will try tomorrow. the job got in the way today :).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with after some observations I've done on paper.

```
class CardShuffle {
    private long k;
    private long n;
    private long kn;
    private long kn2;

    public CardShuffle(long k, long n) {
            //I omitted some checks done here
        this.k = k;
        this.n = n;
        this.kn = k / n;
        this.kn2 = k - kn;
    }

    public long shuffle() {
        long count = 0L;
        long next = 0L;
        do {
               //this can be further optimized
           next = kn2 - kn * (next % n) + (next / n); 
           ++count;
        } while((next != 0L) && (count < k));
        if(count > k)
           return -1;
        return count;
    }
}
```

The results are...

```
Testing 1000000 : 2
#ms: 3.121905
#ms: 1424.487191
#1: 9900 #2: 9900
Testing 1000000 : 5
#ms: 1.409955
#ms: 556.329366
#1: 2475 #2: 2475
Testing 1000000 : 10
#ms: 0.007823
#ms: 186.797204
#1: 12 #2: 12
Testing 1000000 : 20
#ms: 0.590298
#ms: 275.751527
#1: 4950 #2: 4950
Testing 1000000 : 25
#ms: 0.298642
#ms: 260.559372
#1: 2475 #2: 2475
Testing 1000000 : 40
#ms: 1.187581
#ms: 241.956729
#1: 9900 #2: 9900
Testing 1000000 : 50
#ms: 1.187581
#ms: 241.015548
#1: 9900 #2: 9900
Testing 9999999 : 41841
#ms: 14.499887
#ms: 1829.868042
#1: 125000 #2: 125000
Testing 9999999 : 3333333
#ms: 58.119398
#ms: 311.005728
#1: 500000 #2: 500000
Testing 9999999 : 13947
#ms: 52.704185
#ms: 2095.336418
#1: 500000 #2: 500000
```

tested against this input...

```
10
1000000 2
1000000 5
1000000 10
1000000 20
1000000 25
1000000 40
1000000 50
9999999 41841
9999999 3333333
9999999 13947
```

First `#ms` is time in milliseconds it took my method, second is yours.
`#1` and `#2` are the results respectively.

Where-as for this input...

```
15
1000000000 2
1000000000 5
1000000000 10
1000000000 20
1000000000 25
1000000000 40
1000000000 50
1000000000 1000
1000000000 200000000
1000000000 250000000
1000000000 500000000
1000000000 50000000
999999999 1001001
999999999 37037037
999999999 333333333
```

My method finds the solution in

```
Testing 1000000000 : 2
#ms: 71.360466
#1: 525780
Testing 1000000000 : 5
#ms: 68.987259
#1: 525780
Testing 1000000000 : 10
#ms: 0.008381
#1: 18
Testing 1000000000 : 20
#ms: 75.608492
#1: 525780
Testing 1000000000 : 25
#ms: 31.843154
#1: 262890
Testing 1000000000 : 40
#ms: 33.014531
#1: 262890
Testing 1000000000 : 50
#ms: 84.27384
#1: 525780
Testing 1000000000 : 1000
#ms: 0.006705
#1: 6
Testing 1000000000 : 200000000
#ms: 53.991778
#1: 525780
Testing 1000000000 : 250000000
#ms: 43.765898
#1: 262890
Testing 1000000000 : 500000000
#ms: 54.457201
#1: 525780
Testing 1000000000 : 50000000
#ms: 68.080999
#1: 525780
Testing 999999999 : 1001001
#ms: 115.060154
#1: 1000000
Testing 999999999 : 37037037
#ms: 5783.539528
#1: 50000000
Testing 999999999 : 333333333
#ms: 5391.880532
#1: 50000000
```

while yours goes out of memory on the very first one, on my old and slow laptop though.

I haven't validated this approach yet, but looks to me like it works. 
You might try and see if it fails on some inputs. I'd appreciate it.

If you're interested a bit more how I developed the formula, leave a comment.

I too have submitted the solution to *interviewstreet* but it failed on the 4th testcase due to the time limit constraint.

I'll try with a c program very soon and will report here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't have time to check this today, but I'll get back to you.

Comment: I tried out your solution, it's pretty confusing for me. From what I understand, your returned count is never larger than `K` - that's what I draw from the conditional in the while loop and the if statement at the end. If so, how did you get 525780 for N=1000000000 and K=2? I tried running your code and the output was 2 for the same test case.

Comment: @AlexCiminian I mixed up the variables a bit. `K` is `N` in the source :) So, make it `N=2` and `K=1000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Given N and K, work out what permutation that produces, and work out what it looks like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation. In cycle notation, the permutation is a product of disjoint cycles, e.g. ABCDEF => ECAFDB is (AEDFBC) because A->E->D->F->B->C->A. If your permuation is a single cycle like this, the length of the cycle is the number of times you need to repeat it to get back to the same place. If the permuation is a product of multiple disjoint cycles such as (ABC)(DE)(F) the number of times you need to repeat is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple of the lengths of the individual cycles.

Comment: -1, this is identical to Alex's 'first' solution, and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yep, @cmh is right, this is what I did in the first run. If you can find bugs or ways to optimize my code, I'd be grateful, but I don't think you can get the required complexity with this approach.  

I will try to update the question with the terminology you suggested, permutation cycles sounds better than "approach 1". :)

Comment: @AlexCiminian. If you read about [permutation groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) then you may be able to see the link between the two solutions.

Comment: I have coded this up and get about the same speed as the first version posted. As coded it takes O(N) because it takes that long to write out a permutation, and working out the cycle structure is also O(N) as long as you make sure you go round the each cycle only once. Can't think of anything < O(N) I'm afraid.

Comment: The second variant is O( number of factors of  φ(N + 1) ) which is a lot better than O(n), however I get a "wrong answer" for it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong there, in my tests I get the same result for both implementations.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int t, m , n, c, p, k, pos, cases;

    cin>>cases;

    while(cases--)
    {
        cin>>t;
        cin>>k;

        p = t/k;
        pos = 1;
        c = 0;

        do
        {
            c++;
            m = (pos - 1)%p + 1;
            n = k - (pos - m)/p;
            pos = k*(m-1) + n;

        }while(pos!=1);

        cout<<c<<endl;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it times out after the third test.